# DBLinks or REST API to read data from 2 different databases, in an application?

Tags: java, database-design, oracle12c, database-administration, dblink

I have two different Java-based web applications each having two different oracle 12C databases respectively. Both applications consume data via SPRING framework based DAO layers from respective DBs.

Both the databases have 2 tables called `EMP_1` and `EMP_2` respectively wherein they have some common fields(in terms of values but they might have different field names) and `DB#2` have some extra fields as well.

I will try to illustrate how they look:

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+

APP#1 ----------------------------------- APP#2

DB#1(oracle)--------------------------- DB#2(oracle)

EMP_1 table (10 fields)-------------- EMP_2 table (13 fields)

----------------------------------------------------------
```

Now in `APP#1`, I want to fetch the data of 10 fields from `DB#1` and as well as 13 fields from `DB#2` which is used by `APP#2` as well.

Now the question is shall I use DBlinks to connect these databases to fetch data or shall I just create a REST-based API in `APP#2` to expose data from `DB#2` and consume the same API in `APP#1` to merge the data?

Please note the API will only be used in `APP#1` and has no further scope of re-usability.
What are the best practices in such scenarios - Are DBlinks a good approach?

Comment: IMHO DBLink is the best approach as it gives you the full advantage of SQL query processing and avoids turn-around time involved with REST

Comment: @learningloop Thanks for sharing your insight, well i am also inclined towards using DBlinks considering that we will be able to leverage SQL level queries to fetch the data and will have a less latency from performance point of view, and as you mentioned lesser turnaround time then REST, but a lot of people have mentioned about coupling the databases is not a very intuitive way in today's world - so i am still evaluating approaches.

Comment: So i have been reading a lot about ORDS (oracle Rest services build on top of oracle DB), any thoughts on that ?